# Why doesn't guice requestInjection work on Kotlin object

Tags: kotlin, guice

I am new to Guice. I am trying to use requestInjection to inject the dependencies of a kotlin singleton **object** in this way.

**APPROACH 1**:

```
class SampleTest {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        Guice.createInjector(object: KotlinModule() {
            override fun configure() {
                requestInjection(A)
            }
        })
        assertEquals("Hello world", A.saySomething())
    }
}

object A {
    @Inject
    private lateinit var b: B

    fun saySomething(): String {
        return b.sayHello()
    }
}

class B {
    fun sayHello(): String {
        return "Hello world"
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property b has not been initialized
```

If I change A to a class with no-arg constructor, it works.

**APPROACH 2**:

```
class SampleTest {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        val a = A()
        Guice.createInjector(object: KotlinModule() {
            override fun configure() {
                requestInjection(a)
            }
        })
        assertEquals("Hello world", a.saySomething())
    }
}

class A {
    @Inject
    private lateinit var b: B

    fun saySomething(): String {
        return b.sayHello()
    }
}

class B {
    fun sayHello(): String {
        return "Hello world"
    }
}
```

Instead, if I change **requestInjection** to **requestStaticInjection**, it also works.

**APPROACH 3**:

```
class SampleTest {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        Guice.createInjector(object: KotlinModule() {
            override fun configure() {
                requestStaticInjection<A>()
            }
        })
        assertEquals("Hello world", A.saySomething())
    }
}

object A {
    @Inject
    private lateinit var b: B

    fun saySomething(): String {
        return b.sayHello()
    }
}

class B {
    fun sayHello(): String {
        return "Hello world"
    }
}
```

Why didn't **APPROACH 1** work? Why did **APPROACH 2** and **APPROACH 3** work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin's objects are treated as language static singletons, i.e. their initialization/instantiations happens outside the scope of the dependency injection framework.

Therefor, when using the `KotlinModule` to inject an object, you have to use `requestStaticInjection` like in **APPROACH 3**, or change that object to a class, so that the Guice `KotlinModule` sees it as `non-static`, as presented in **APPROACH 2**

Hope that clarifies things a bit.